# how to sum values according to previous document's value and next document's value in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Im Strugling with some aggregation functions in mongodb.

Say I have some documents like this in two collections:

collection A:

```
{index: "1", time: 10:30:00, value: 12}
{index: "2", time: 10:30:20, value: 11}
{index: "1", time: 10:30:32, value: 15}
{index: "2", time: 10:31:05, value: 13}
{index: "1", time: 10:31:40, value: 14}
{index: "2", time: 10:31:43, value: 10}
```

collection B:

```
{index: "1", time: 10:30:10, cost: 10}
{index: "2", time: 10:30:15, cost: 12}
{index: "1", time: 10:30:30, cost: 8}
{index: "2", time: 10:30:50, cost: 9}
{index: "1", time: 10:31:10, cost: 10}
{index: "2", time: 10:31:23, cost: 11}
```

And i want to return this:

```
{index: "1", value: 12, totalCost: 18}
{index: "1", value: 15, totalCost: 10}
{index: "1", value: 14, totalCost: 0}
{index: "2", value: 11, totalCost: 9}
{index: "2", value: 13, totalCost: 9}
{index: "2", value: 10, totalCost: 11}
```

The `{index: "1", value: 12, totalCost: 18}` of result meaning that:

According to collection A's documents' that index = "1" and  time between 10:30:00 and 10:30:32,  querying collection B's documents which index = "1" and time is between 10:30:00 and 10:30:32 and then sum its cost as totalCost.

Does mongodb aggregate can implement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we need to use several operators.

**BTW:** Please provide valid expectation, since your result based on sample data is wrong

```
{index: "1", value: 12, totalCost: 18} -> OK
{index: "1", value: 14, totalCost: 0}  -> OK
{index: "1", value: 15, totalCost: 10} -> OK
{index: "2", value: 10, totalCost: 11} -> KO (No B document greater than 10:31:43)
{index: "2", value: 11, totalCost: 9}  -> OK
{index: "2", value: 13, totalCost: 9}  -> KO (For 10:31:05 - 10:31:43, matchs only {index: "2", time: 10:31:23, cost: 11})
```

### Pipeline explanation

1. [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) is used to contruct hierarchy for given `index` value.
2. We need to remove from hierarchy:

   - node with the same `_id` as parent
   - all children lower than parent `time`
   - take closest `time` to parent's `time` value
3. We join collection `B` and take items:

   - Same `index` as `A` documents
   - B's `time` is between A's parent `time` and A's child `time`
4. We transform into desired result and sum `totalCost`

---

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "A",
      startWith: "$index",
      connectFromField: "index",
      connectToField: "index",
      as: "range"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      range: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$range",
          initialValue: {
            index: "$index",
            time: "23:59:59",
            value: 0
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $ne: [ "$_id", "$$this._id" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [ "$$this.time", "$time" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lt: [ "$$this.time", "$$value.time" ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      let: {
        index: "$index",
        start: "$time",
        end: "$range.time"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [ "$$index", "$index" ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gt: [ "$time", "$$start" ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lt: [ "$time", "$$end" ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "linked"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      index: 1,
      value: 1,
      totalCost: { $sum: "$linked.cost" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      index: 1,
      value: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L9WNBDV5KsM)